# Display loading animation while part of page loads via jQuery's load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

On my site I want to load "pages" dynamicly via jQuery's `load()` function and I would like to add a loading animation.

```
function loadPage(){
  $("#content").load("example.html");
}
```

Where would I put code to show `<div id="loading"></div>` while jQuery loads that content??

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the callback function of `.load()` to hide the loading div when it is finished.

```
function loadPage(){
    $('#loading').show();

    $("#content").load("example.html", function () { //calback function
         $('#loading').hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSend(function() {
        $(this).append('<div id="loading"></div>');
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $('#loading').remove();
    });
});
```

Which will work for all of your ajax calls...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but probably you want to load content to a `div`.
You should create a css class:

```
.loading {
  background: url(loading.gif) center center;
}
```

and add this class to your div (after you clear it) with `addClass()` when you start loading, and remove it  with `removeClass` in `.load` callback.